# Page not found when working with apiResource

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the following simple project:

`App\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php` which includes all the API methods (`store`, `show`, `update`, `destroy`)

`App\Http\Resources\ProductResource.php` which returns a JSON

`App\Models\Product.php` which just has the `protected fillable` array

and finally `App\routes\api.php` with the following code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;


Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class);
```

But when I try to `POST` some example product using Postman, I get `404 Not Found`.

The URL I post to is `localhost:8000/api/products.store`, because from what I understand is that `apiResource` simply creates all the named routes in the form of `products.method_name`

*By the way, the URL `localhost:8000/api/products` returns an empty `{"data":[]}`

I'm clearly doing something wrong - what is it?

Comment: Can you please run the command php artisan route:list and send the snap shot of routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use the route name in the URL like this,
the request should be like:

```
localhost:8000/api/products/store
```

try this command

```
 php artisan route:list
```

and you will see all your routes and the URL that you should use for each one

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add Accept: application/json in header.